# high resolution data around a pipe needs downsampling including wrap around the edges

Tags: python, arrays, function, scipy

I got data from a tubular pipe, which have 360 samples around (azimuth wise each 1 degree), and I need to downsample to 72 samples. Given the physics and resolutions of the measurement I am comparing, each of the 72 samples is an average of approx. 15 of the 360 samples.

the traditional approach of downsampling by slicing will not let me have the proper downsampling, and in facts shifts the data. I tried averaging in 5-slice interval (to match 360/72) but also appears shifted

In order to truly compare these measurements, I need to downsample the high resolution data to the same resolution of the other measurement.

problem: I need to create each of the 72 columns of this array by averaging 15 of the original array, which means I need to be able to wrap the average function over the main array. I want ultimately to create:

1- a moving window including over the edge wrap, which I can select the size of the window
2- to select what is the "step" of calculating this window, so I can have a final output of as many columns I need to match my measurement
3- the new downsampled array, I will perform computations on it

Tried with the average of 5 slices, but the resulting image does not look as the input due to the lack of edge averaging, plus each 5 slices is not truly overlapping the lower resolution measurement

```
avesize=5 #360/72 =5
ave_array=[] 
for i in range(0, len(a), avesize):
    slice_from_index = i
    slice_to_index = slice_from_index + avesize
    ave_array.append(np.average(a[slice_from_index:slice_to_index]))
```

Comment: Could you provide a small example of the data? It sounds more like an interpolation problem (interpolating the 360 samples dataset at the points of the 72samples dataset) or if there is noise in the data a curve fitting problem or smoothing (least square spline fitting for example)

Comment: Tried copying some of it in this window, but too big. Will try to attach (don't see a button for it though)

the interpolation part I think is the least of my problems, but is more about how to get a "circular" array with a sample each degree, and make a moving average that wraps at the edges, with n-degrees size moving window

Comment: is your data 1d? you could create some false data representative of the problem, for example `x = [0, 1, 2, 3]` and `y = [7, 6, 8, 9]`, 10-20 points should be enough to get the idea of the question. It will help us to understand the question and to answer appropriately

Comment: lets say my X is a matrix of 6rows x 10cols <br />
[[0.402,0.402,0.403,0.405,0.405,0.41,0.412,0.413,0.416,0.415]
[0.404,0.405,0.409,0.409,0.414,0.415,0.415,0.415,0.413,0.413]
[0.403,0.405,0.407,0.412,0.412,0.413,0.414,0.413,0.414,0.414]
[0.406,0.409,0.412,0.413,0.413,0.412,0.413,0.413,0.413,0.413]
[0.404,0.406,0.408,0.412,0.412,0.412,0.413,0.414,0.414,0.413]
[0.4,0.401,0.404,0.405,0.408,0.411,0.412,0.413,0.413,0.413]
]

The resulting averaging over a circle **in the first row** is, and downsampled to 5col is <br /> [[0.4055, 0.40375, 0.408, 0.41275, 0.4115]]

Comment: if for example I use excel, I will use 4 colunms for the average, and each step is two colums

Assuming the X array is in excel [A1:J6], then the first row averages are : <br/>
[AVERAGE(A1:C1,J1),  AVERAGE(B1:E1),  AVERAGE(D1:G1),  AVERAGE(F1:I1),  AVERAGE(A1,H1:J1)] <br/>

note that the first and last elements of the resulting average are wrapping around. I hope this clarify the matter